# How to log execution of sequence called by scheduled task?

Tags: wso2, log4j, task, sequence

Is it possible to log execution of sequence called by scheduled task with log4j  configuration on WSO2 5.0 instance. 
The sequence is calling by scheduled task with "injectTo" and "Sequence name" properties. The web service has log4j configuration but when the sequence is calling from the scheduled task nothing is written inside the log file.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Log mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Log+Mediator) inside your sequence definition.

For example:

```
<log level="full" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
```

You should see the message information in the `{esb_home}/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log` file when your scheduled task kicks off.

Comment: Thanks, i use log mediator,  but i want to log the sequence activity in the log file of the service defined with log4j in log4j.property or different  log  , not in wso2carbon.log where all web services writes inside.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "The web service has log4j configuration" or "the service defined with log4j in log4j.property". Do you mean you have enabled per-service logs in the ESB (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Per-Service+Logs+in+WSO2+ESB) ?

Comment: Yes,  per-service logs is enabled. Sorry, I had to write it first.